# Pass different sorts of arguments to Vectorize()

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I am currently trying to improve myself in efficiently testing several models against each other. My attempt for which I've provided sample code can be described as follows:

For a given dependent variable (column 11 in `data`), linear models which differ by their explanatory input variables are estimated. My wish is to have a pair of parameters `a` and `b` which determine the start and end column for the selection of explanatory variables in my data frame `data`.

These parameter combinations I have saved in `parameters`. I'd like to add a column containing the evaluation of some measure (here `df.residual`) given the parameters in its row.

I fail, however, in vectorizing the problem. More specifically, I pass `a` and `b` correctly, but not `data`.

```
# Example data
data = as.data.frame(mtcars)

# Setting the parameters for choosing x-columns
# a is the start column, b the end column
parameters = tidyr::expand(tibble(a=1:5, b = 1:5 * 2),a,b) %>%
dplyr::filter(a<b)


# Define the function called to yield the result
another_fun = function(a, b, data) {    
# Vectorize, here's some trouble
  case_fun_another = Vectorize( 
    function(a, b, data=data) {
      x = as.matrix(data[,a:b])
      y = as.matrix(data[,11])
      lm.fit(x=x,y=y)$df.residual
    }, SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )

 output = case_fun_another(a, b)
 return(output)
}

# Calculate result
parameters = dplyr::mutate(parameters, result=another_fun(a, b, data))
```

that yields:

`promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`

The questions I found to this topic weren't quite comprehensible to me. Maybe with the description of the problem it becomes easier.

Any idea of how to deal with it? I'd also be open to other options than using Vectorize :-)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @李哲源 Zheyuan Li: Kudos - that helped, I just learnt a lot, thanks :-) Will accept this as an answer once I can.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative without dealing with nested function and Vectorize.

```
# get all the possible pairwise combination of independent variables with combn
ind.var <- names(data)[-11] %>%
         combn(., 2) %>% 
         t

head(ind.var)

#       [,1]  [,2]  
# [1,] "mpg" "cyl" 
# [2,] "mpg" "disp"
# [3,] "mpg" "hp"  
# [4,] "mpg" "drat"
# [5,] "mpg" "wt"  
# [6,] "mpg" "qsec"


# paste values of each row of ind.var, with separator "+"

x <- do.call(paste, c(as.list(data.frame(ind.var, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), sep="+"))
y <- "carb"

# write out all the linear model formula:

forms <- mapply(function(a,b) paste(a, b, sep="~"), y, x) %>%
      setNames(NULL)

all.lm <- lapply(forms, function(x) eval(bquote(lm(.(x), data=data))))

all.lm[[1]]

# Call:
#   lm(formula = "carb~mpg+cyl", data = data)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          mpg          cyl  
#     3.63978     -0.09968      0.18995
```

Thanks to @Roland for pointing out the usage of `bquote` for retaining the formula call in lm.object.

Comment: You shouldn't parse anyway. Your last sentence can be addressed like this: `f <- Sepal.Length ~ .; eval(bquote(lm(.(f), data = iris)))` (using a different example for simplicity). Parsing text should always be avoided.

Comment: The example works well, thank you.I have to study whether I can extend it to the desired parametrization.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for alerting me to `bquote`. I'll clean up the code when I can.